# An "still running" program wont let me shut down inmediately

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, mate

i am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with MATE 1.20.1
I tried to install different desktops environments alongside MATE. While installing/uninstalling some desktops environments every time (only in MATE) i shut down the computer a windows shows up.Like this one:

[image: Like this one]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot!